# Change to conventional algebra notations

Tags: code-golf

**The Challenge**

Given an algebraic expression (eg `2ab`, change it so it follows standard convention rules.

**The Rules**

- Letters should be in alphabetical order. ie `2ab` is allowed but not `2ba`.
- Numbers should always go first. ie `2ab` is allowed but `ab2` is not.
- Exponentiation will be given as `a^b` to mean `a` to the power of `b`.
- These rules must be applied to every sub-expression. ie `2ab + ba3` becomes `2ab + 3ab`, `2vd * vd5` becomes `2dv * 5dv`. **This must work for at least addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, modulus and exponentiation.**
- Exponentiation is assumed to belong to the variable immediately preceding it and must stay with the variable it is assigned to. ie `2ba^2` becomes `2a^2b`. This means that all variables to the right of `^` are part of the exponentiation.

**Sample Input/Output**

Input can be given with any amount of white space, which must be ignored. Output can use either one space or none. For example, `2ab               +3ba` could become `2ab + 3ab` or `2ab+3ab`

```
Input -> Output
2ba -> 2ab
4gb + 5vh * gh7 -> 4bg + 5hv * 7gh
2ba^2 -> 2a^2b
5xk^2ba -> 5k^2abx
```

(The last couple of outputs don't make sense mathematically because of order of operations, but you don't have to worry about that.)

**Scoring**

Standard code golf, shortest answer in bytes wins. Answer can be a program which takes input, or a function (can be anonymous).

Comment: Do we have to deal with expressions like `2a2b` or `2aba`?

Comment: @MartinEnder No.

Comment: “This must work for at least addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, modulus and exponentiation.” You should add test cases for these, then. (Although I advise you just simplify the challenge.)

Comment: You should maybe write an EBNF-like description of the possible input strings. Will there be parentheses? Spaces halfway through a monomial?

Comment: Can you provide an example of an expression with multiple exponents? I am not sure what the output will look like.

Comment: @xsot Such as `2ab^fg3^re8 -> 2ab^3fg^8er`?

Comment: So "ba2^3" becomes "2a^3b"?

Comment: @Neil You can assume that every `^` is preceded by a variable rather than a number.

Comment: Ugh, finished my answer only to find the question is now on hold... `s=>s.replace(/ /g,'').replace(/[\w^]+/g,g=w=>w.match(/\d+|\w(\^.*)?/g).map(t=>t.replace(/(?!^)\b\w.*/,g)).sort().join\`\`)`

Comment: @Neil, the reason it has been put on hold is to fix unclear parts of the specification which might make that answer no longer work. Hopefully the spec will be fixed, the question will be reopened, and you can fix anything which needs fixing in your answer in order to comply with the clarified spec.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 112 + 1 (`p` flag) = 113 bytes

Run as `ruby -pe` with the code surrounded by single quotes. Full program, even if it looks like just a recursive function at the beginning.

```
f=->s{s.scan(/(\w)(\^.+)?/).map{|a,b|[a,b&&?^,b&&f[b]]}.sort_by &:first};gsub(/[\w^]+/){f[$&]*""};gsub(/\s+/,"")
```